# I want to rebuild my Stencil.js project from a build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, stenciljs, rebuild

**My project was erased and I only have the build.**

I wanted to deployment my stencil project in server, using "WWW" output, but I have some problems, for that I tried to use some propertys in this doc:

https://stenciljs.com/docs/www

I wasn't understand the "DIR" property (I don't now what is a: "web distribution directory"), for that i added the next code In the "stencil.config.ts" file.

```
dir: ".",
```

The result:

```
import { Config } from '@stencil/core';
export const config: Config = {
  namespace: 'cosmo',
  outputTargets: [
    {
      type: 'dist',
      esmLoaderPath: '../loader',
    },
    {
      type: 'dist-custom-elements',
    },
    {
      type: 'docs-readme',
    },
    {
      type: 'www',
      dir: ".",
      serviceWorker: null, // disable service workers
    },
  ],
};
```

When I put the command "npm run build" in the terminal, all my project was erased, including the ".git" archives, but the image in the "assets" folder were not deleted. I can't recovery the proyect, but I have the "build". for that I wanted to recovery my project using the build.

[My erased project, only have the folders, all is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCfOD.png)

¿I can rebuild my project using the build? (I'm not desperate, I was just starting out, I could rebuild everything in one day)

[Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOHHy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restore some of the code, yes. But probably not the types unless you have a `dist` backup as well.

Start by looking at the files that have the same name as your components and end in `.entry.js`. These are the main component files. If you imported an external function into a component it might also be in this file. I'd recommend creating a new Stencil project, generating a component and then copying the code from the entry file.

The main things you'll have to change:

1. Add the properties including the decorators (e.g. `@Prop`). If they were initialised with a value they should be in the constructor. Watchers are defined in a `watchers()` getter, `@Element` to a `el()` getter. `@Event`s are defined in the constructor with a `createEvent` function. `@Listen`s (as well as some more data about `@Prop`s (such as whether they reflect their value) can be found in `app.esm.js` but that involves diving into the flags that Stencil uses (if you had set a custom namespace then replace "app".
2. Move the CSS from the JS string to a CSS file.
3. Change the render function to TSX. The built files will have calls to [an `h()` function](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/blob/main/src/runtime/vdom/h.ts) with the following parameters: `d(tagName, properties, ...children)`
   1 . Do the same for any files which might be imported from the entry file.

**Example:** 
Minified:

```
  render() {
    return (h("div", { class: "app-home" }, h("p", null, "Welcome to the Stencil App Starter.")));
  }
```

Un-minified:

```
  render() {
    return <div class="app-home">
      <p>Welcome to the Stencil App Starter.</p>
    </div>;
  }
```